# Plurals don't work in xml

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to load plurals in the error text in my `TextInputEditText`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/et_subject_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@{ model.name }"
    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
    app:validateRegex='@{"^*\\S{2}.*$"}'
    app:validateRegexMessage="@{@plurals/error_too_short(model.minNameLength)}"/>
```

But in my app it shows my string but with `%d` instead of `model.minNameLength` value. The `app:validateRegex` is an attribute is defined by [Data Binding Validator](https://github.com/Ilhasoft/data-binding-validator) library.
My plurals:

```
<plurals name="error_too_short">
    <item quantity="one" >Too short, enter at least %d visible character.</item>
    <item quantity="other" >Too short, enter at least %d visible characters.</item>
</plurals>
```

What's wrong? Or has it a some another way to show plurals in xml?
P.S. I use a data binding engine V2 if it's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<plurals name="recent_messages">
    <item quantity="zero">No Recent Messages</item>
    <item quantity="one">1 Recent Message</item>
    <item quantity="other">%1$d Recent Messages</item>
</plurals>

mContext.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.recent_messages, count, count);
```

Comment: You can use `%d`.

Answer (score 22):

In the official [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals):

> When using the [getQuantityString()](/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getQuantityString(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object...)) method, you need to pass the count twice if your string includes
>   string formatting with a number. For example, for the string
>   %d songs found, the first count parameter selects the appropriate plural string and
>   the second count parameter is inserted into the %d placeholder. If your plural
>   strings do not include string formatting, you don't need to pass the third parameter to [getQuantityString](/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getQuantityString(int,%20int)).

So, as you want `model.minNameLength` to define which plural version to select as well as to insert its value in the string, you should provide it twice. So, the *databinding* expression should instead be like:

```
app:validateRegexMessage="@{@plurals/error_too_short(model.minNameLength, model.minNameLength)}"
```

Comment: Nice answer. Kudos!